# Is there a way to issue a warning when running tests with XCTest?

Tags: xcode, xctest

I have a project that imports a Git submodule to run a part of an XCTest test suite. If the submodule is not available (not checked out), I want the test suite to succeed, but issue a warning that not all tests were run. Is that possible?

Comment: I think this is not possible.

Comment: I would like this, too, as I have tests for iOS9-specific code that I want to succeed when testing on iOS9, but _not_ fail when testing on ≤8.

Answer (score 2):

Searching for similar issue I have found out that we could add messages to test logs as string attachments. If you want to have a warning sign you can add ⚠️ emoji in name.
Here is a function example that adds it.

```
    func addLogMessage(_ message: String, attachmentLifetime: XCTAttachment.Lifetime = .keepAlways) {
        XCTContext.runActivity(named: "Log message") { activity in
            let messageAttachment = XCTAttachment(string: message)
            messageAttachment.lifetime = attachmentLifetime
            activity.add(messageAttachment)
        }
    }
```